# MS Access to manage WordPress Database

Tags: database, users, buddypress

Now I don't believe this is practical or possible without a large amount of development. My client's old site used MS Access to manage the user's profiles on his old website.

His new site uses BuddyPress to manage user profiles, his old site was a bespoke WordPress members system.

I'm just trying to get a concrete answer from someone who knows - is it practical or possible to manage users from MS Access or is it more hassle then it's worth.

Cheers!

Comment: AFAIK not practical and IMHO not worth it.

Comment: Probably possible, but very specialized. And your question has the only occurrence of ["MS Access"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22MS+Access%22) on the site.

Comment: I figured as much, thanks guys :) Yeah I found no other articles mentioning MS Access. I'm just going to build pop out profile editor that will let him edit profiles on the fly from the Dashboard rather than bringing him to the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know something about databases, and have access to the back end SQL database (most likely through Cpanel/phpMyAdmin, you can see the structure of the database, including the columns (fields) and their attributes. Knowing this, you can export an Access query into an Excel file with the same fields and attributes as the BuddyPress SQL table, save the Excel file as a csv file, then import the csv file through phpMyAdmin's import function.

I've done this several times. I don't use BuddyPress, so I don't have the table structure, but you can design all your query exports to Excel to match the SQL structure of the tables in question.